# How do I in object mode, cull back faces?

Tags: interface

Where is "Back-face culling" turned on for object mode?

Please indicate a path for reaching this control. eg: click on ____, then press ____, then scroll down to ___, etc. As I find it difficult to find my way around Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *3D view > Properties Region* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Shading > Backface Culling*:

[image]

Comment: @EricHuelin Glad I could help :) If this post satisfactorily answers your question, [consider marking it as accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).